# Context Sensitive Lindenmayer System

Tags: context-sensitive-grammar, context-sensitive-help

I'm working on implementation the ContextSensitive L-system from "Algoritmic Beauty of Plants", but I don't get the same results as in the book.

If i correctly understood when I have axiom like this:

```
0 < 1 > 0 -> 1F1
1 < 0 > 1 -> 1
1 < 1 > 1 -> 0
#ignore +-F
```

and

```
F1F0F1[-F1F1][+F1F1]F0
```

There is only 1 change

```
F1F0F1[-F1F1][+F1F1]F0
```

into

```
F1F1F1F1[-F1F1][+F1F1]F0
```

So how can I interpret the `[]` signs? Am I omitting it or what?

Comment: Is there any reason for C++ tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the answer on other posts.